# acessando dados da classe em uma função no escopo global com typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, youtube-api

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Angular 2 e estou usando a API do Youtube. A API do Youtube exige que eu implemente algumas funções no escopo global, então fiz o seguinte:

```
export class MyClass {

  dados: any;

  constructor( ... ) {
    ...
  }

  loadAPI(){
    (window as any).onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
      buildPlayer();
    }

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    console.log('API loaded');
  }

}

function buildPlayer(){
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
  console.log('youtube iframe api ready!');
}

function onPlayerReady(event){
  // AQUI ESTÁ O PROBLEMA
  // Eu quero manipular "dados" dentro dessas funções.
}

function onPlayerStateChange(status){
  // AQUI ESTÁ O PROBLEMA
  // Eu quero manipular "dados" dentro dessas funções.
}
```

O código carrega a API corretamente e cria o player, porém não consigo manipular os dados da variável que está dentro da classe nestas funções. Alguma ideia de como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Qual variável você precisa alterar?

Comment: coloquei aquela variável "dados" só como um exemplo, digamos que ela está com dados vindos do banco, preciso que esses dados sejam passados para estas funções abaixo.

Comment: Você tá criando as funções fora da classe, por isso não consegue acessar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que a variável `dados` faz parte do escopo da classe e estas funções estão declaradas **fora da classe**, apenas ajuste isso.

Declarar a variável dados fora da classe vai permitir que ela seja acessada fora da classe.

```
dados: any;

export class MyClass {    

    constructor() {

    }

    loadAPI(){
    (window as any).onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
      buildPlayer();
    }

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    console.log('API loaded');
    }
} 

function buildPlayer(){
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
  console.log('youtube iframe api ready!');
}

function onPlayerReady(event){
    //a variável dados pode ser acessada aqui
    console.log(dados);   
}

function onPlayerStateChange(status){
    //a variável dados pode ser acessada aqui
    console.log(dados);        
}
```

Comment: Aí que tá, se eu coloco estas funções dentro da classe, a API do Youtube não as "enxerga". Elas precisam estar do lado de fora.

Comment: Então declara a variável em cima do `export class MyClass `.

Comment: Nossa, tão simples e eu viajando tentando fazer coisas complexas hahah. Era isso mesmo, valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: É válido colocar também que a variável pode, também, ser acessada na classe e não só nas funções fora dela. Muito obrigado!